# Was the story of Great deluge taken from Rig Vedic mantras?

Tags: puranas, rig-veda

The story of [Great deluge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shraddhadeva_Manu#The_Great_Deluge) was narrated in  Satapatha Brahmana , Bhagavata Purana and the Matsya Purana, as well as in the Mahabharata.

However, I have found the following epithets from Rig Veda.

Rig veda [III.27](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv03027.htm) was dedicated to Agni

> धिया चक्रे वरेण्यो भूतानां गर्भमा दधे | दक्षस्यपितरं तना || 9
>
> He was made supreme by the insight . **I have held the seed of all
>   beings, the father of discernment in an extended form**.
>
> नि तवा दधे वरेण्यं दक्षस्येळा सहस्क्र्त | अग्ने सुदीतिमुशिजम ||  10
>
> I have placed you supreme, you who are made by strength, by the word
>   of discernment, O Agni, shining brightly and inspired
>
> अग्निं यन्तुरमप्तुरं रतस्य योगे वनुषः | विप्रा वाजैः समिन्धते ||   11
>
> The Fire, the controller, ***who crosses the waters,*** in the Yoga of
>   truth, the sages enkindle you with power

---

Agni or Indra or Vishnu, etc, was eulogised as Brahman in Rig Veda.

Can we infer from the epithets mentioned in **bold form**, that the story of Great deluge was taken from Rig Veda?

Comment: Ralph T. Griffith is an old and poor translator of Sanskrit. His translations have many errors. It is better to look for the same verses from a different translator.

Comment: Can you suggest some other translator's version please?  Swami Vishwananda